# unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFindChainInStore C++ SCHANNEL

Tags: c++, schannel

unresolved external symbol __imp_CertFindChainInStore compile error

seems if i include CertFindChainInStore my program wont compile
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certfindchaininstore

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You need to link with `Crypt32.lib`.

Comment: You're asking us to solve a problem with code we cannot see. You need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: well paul i think that could do it

Comment: and i  works thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to link Crypt32.lib to address that function

add this at beggning of your cpp file

```
 #pragma comment ( lib, "Crypt32.lib" )
```